# Gotomeeting Webinar

Tags: wine

Is there a way to participate in a Gotomeeting webinnar with Ubuntu 12.04?

This are the system requirements:

> ```
> Internet connection
> Windows 7, Vista, 2003 Server or XP
> Mac OS X v10.5 Leopard or newer
> iPad 1 or newer, iPhone 3GS or newer, iPod touch (3rd generation) or newer with Mac iOS v4.2 or newer, Android 2.2 or newer
> Internet Explorer 7.0 or newer, Firefox 4.0 or newer, Safari 3.0 or newer or Chrome 5.0 or newer
> ```

Thanks

Comment: not yet. In Wine Is equal to that with firefox or explorer?

Answer (score 1):

i also cannot play the g2m coded videos, but i found another solution to convert the files and make it playable on any machine with any player. check out the link below:

[GoToMeeting Codecs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232236/ubuntu-12-10-gotomeeting-codecs)