# GoToMeeting Codecs

Tags: software-installation

I have plenty of `*.wmv` files (webinars recorded by GoToMeeting and downloaded). Now I cannot watch the files anymore since I switched from Windows to Ubuntu. I tried to install the gotomeeting-codecs with Wine and copied the `G2M.dll` into `/usr/lib/codec`s. but still does not work. Any ideas how to fix the problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can play any media file following this: [How to install all existing media codecs?](http://askubuntu.com/q/171026/65926)

Comment: thanks for answering with the link above. it didn't help for me - i cannot run this gotomeeting coded video-files. but i found another solution that works. installed the gotomeeting-codecs and the  "any video converter" on windows in a virtual machine. copied the g2m.dll from gotomeeting folder into the codecs folder from the any video converter installation. now i can drag all my codec-coded videos into the converter program and let it run. it is some work to do, but after all this files can be played on any machine with any player.

Comment: Nice. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I have solved the problem like that; it was some work to do but it works:

Installed the `gotomeeting-codecs` and the "any video converter" on windows in a virtual machine. Copied the `g2m.dll` from gotomeeting folder into the codecs folder from the any video converter installation. Now I can drag all my codec-coded videos into the converter program and let it run. It is some work to do, but after all this files can be played on any machine with any player.